# Error Message: "Project build error: Non-parseable POM

Tags: java, maven

```
<project >xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"> xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>MavenCucumberPrototype</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>MavenCucumberPrototype</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        </project>
```

Comment: Please fix the code section. And you're missing the `<dependencies>` opening tag.

Comment: Thank you, the code is fixed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've got an end-tag *dependencies*  but no start-tag *dependencies*

(missing tag should be between properties-tag and first dependency)

Answer (score 8):

My problem was a internet problem while download the dependencies, so some files was breaking. I solved deleting the directory ".m2" and executing mvn clean install to re-install the dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the `<dependencies>` tag missing, you have a problem on the `<project>` tag as well. This should do it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>MavenCucumberPrototype</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>MavenCucumberPrototype</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Thank you dambros, really appreciate as i am just beginner in IT

Comment: @Vikas no problem. If the answer fixed your issue, mark it as correct to possibly help others in the future.

Comment: @dambros, I have the same error, but my pom looks good. I downloaded starter spring project. Not able to figure out what's going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This mostly happens when you changes versions of eclipse on a single system. Try clearing .m2 directory. It should resolve the issue.

Answer (score -1):

Do Project->Clean, just clean up the project and the error is gone.